# How to Group rows in tdxDBgrid

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-5

I am using Delphi and DevExpress component TdxDBgrid as Grid, TdxMemData as dataset. I am trying to group the records which having same column value 'Master' under one row and on expanding that Master row we can see child rows in the grid. I am trying to find example for this but not able to get any. Does any one know any example or does anyone did same kind of group rows in Grid. Suggestions are welcome.  Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the ShowGroupPanel property of the grid to True. Then, drag a column header of the grid onto the group panel (displayed above the column headers) to group by that column. You can group by columns in code, too, by doing something like

```
dxDGrid1Column1.GroupIndex := 0; 
dxDGrid1Column2.GroupIndex := 1;
```

ISTR this is explained in the OLH and illustrated in the examples.